# How to create container to display incoming and outgoing messages in messenger application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing messenger application in wpf.

And I want to create control to display messages in chat room

I want to make it like in windowsphone's messages apps or any other smartphones' way of displaying incoming and outgoing messages.

Incoming messages on the left, outgoing messages - on the right and sort them by timestamp.

I've looked to telerik control toolkit's examples. There they used whole container to display all the messages sorted by timestamp you specify datatemplate for incoming and outgoing messages to work with it. But the problem is telerik is not free toolkit. So I have to do it by myself.

Here is example of what I want

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MessagesViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Here are templates for incoming and outgoing messages

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IncomingMessageTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="12,12">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel>

                <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                                                                      PointerDirection="Top"
                                                                     TargetPoint="-141,-100">
                    <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Polygon Width="14"
                                     Height="28"
                                     Points="0,14 0,28 14,14"
                                     StrokeThickness="0"
                                     Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                                <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform Y="-2"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                            </Polygon>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" MinHeight="54"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"
                                       Margin="8, 2, 8, 6"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedTimeStamp}"
                                   Margin="8, 2, 8, 2"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"

                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>

            </StackPanel>
            </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OutgoingMessageTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="12,12">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">

                <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl 
                     PointerDirection="bottom"
                                                             TargetPoint="145, -100">
                    <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" Opacity="0.5"/>
                    </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.Background>
                    <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Polygon Width="14"
                                     Height="28"
                                     Points="0,14 0,28 14,14"
                                     StrokeThickness="0">
                                <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                                <Polygon.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                </Polygon.Fill>
                            </Polygon>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>

                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" MinHeight="54"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"
                                           Margin="8, 2, 8, 6"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedTimeStamp}"
                                   Margin="8, 2, 8, 2"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="right"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0, 74, 0, 12">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            PointerDirection="bottom"         TargetPoint="199, -100">
                <telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Polygon Width="14"
                                 Height="28"
                                 Points="0,14 0,28 14,14"
                                 StrokeThickness="0">
                            <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="-32"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                        </Polygon>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl.PointerTemplate>

                <telerikPrimitives:RadTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                                      Watermark="chat on Facebook"
                                                      Margin="0,-5,0,20"
                                                      AcceptsReturn="True"
                                                      ActionButtonVisibility="Visible">
                    <telerikPrimitives:RadTextBox.ActionButtonStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerikTextBox:TextBoxActionButton">
                            <Setter Property="ButtonType"
                                            Value="Custom"/>
                            <Setter Property="RestStateImageSource"
                                            Value="Images/SendIcon.png"/>
                        </Style>
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadTextBox.ActionButtonStyle>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadTextBox>
            </telerikPrimitivesNamespace:RadPointerContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here is what I want - control to view conversations according to incoming and outgoing message templates

```
<telerikData:RadConversationView Grid.Row="0" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
                                         x:Name="conversationView" TextBoxTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}"
                                         Margin="12, 0" IncomingMessageTemplate="{StaticResource IncomingMessageTemplate}" OutgoingMessageTemplate="{StaticResource OutgoingMessageTemplate}"
                                         SendingMessage="OnSendingMessage" />
```

Here is MessagesModelView for this control

```
public class MessagesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private const int DefaultUserId = 4;
    private ObservableCollection<CustomMessage> messages;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people;
    private Person you;
    private Person conversationBuddy;
    private int currentGroup = 0;
    private CustomMessage previousMessage;

    private void InitializeMessages()
    {
        this.messages = new ObservableCollection<CustomMessage>();
        this.messages.CollectionChanged += this.OnMessagesCollectionChanged;

    }

    private void OnMessagesCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        CustomMessage message = e.NewItems[0] as CustomMessage;
        if (previousMessage != null)
        {
            if (previousMessage.SenderId != message.SenderId)
            {
                this.currentGroup++;
            }
        }
        if (message.Group == null)
        {
            message.Group = this.currentGroup;
        }
        previousMessage = message;
    }

    private void InitializePeople()
    {
        this.people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Person person = new Person() { PersonId = i, Name = "PERSON " + i, Picture = new Uri("Images/FrameThumbnail.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };
            this.people.Add(person);
        }
    }

    public Person You
    {
        get
        {
            return this.you;
        }
        set
        {
            this.you = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("You");
        }
    }

    public Person ConversationBuddy
    {
        get
        {
            return this.conversationBuddy;
        }
        set
        {
            this.conversationBuddy = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ConversationBuddy");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomMessage> Messages
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.messages == null)
            {
                this.InitializeMessages();
            }
            return this.messages;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.messages = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.people == null)
            {
                this.InitializePeople();
            }
            return this.people;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.people = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomMessage : ConversationViewMessage, IComparable
{
    public CustomMessage(string text, DateTime timeStamp, ConversationViewMessageType type, int senderId, int? group = null)
        : base(text, timeStamp, type)
    {
        this.SenderId = senderId;
        this.Group = group;
    }

    public int SenderId
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int? Group
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public SolidColorBrush MessageBackground
    {
        get
        {
            int id = this.SenderId % 6;
            switch (id)
            {
                case 0: return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 51, 153, 51));
                case 1: return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 27, 161, 226));
                case 2: return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 151));
                case 3: return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 150, 9));
                case 4: return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 171, 169));
                case 5: return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 140, 191, 38));
            }
            return App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }
    }

    public string FormattedTimeStamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TimeStamp.ToShortTimeString();
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        CustomMessage secondMessage = obj as CustomMessage;

        if (obj is DataGroup)
        {
            secondMessage = (obj as DataGroup).Key as CustomMessage;
        }

        return this.Group == secondMessage.Group;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Group.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        CustomMessage targetMessage = obj as CustomMessage;

        if (targetMessage != null)
        {
            return this.Group > targetMessage.Group ? 1 : this.Group == targetMessage.Group ? 0 : -1;
        }

        if (obj is DataGroup)
        {
            targetMessage = (obj as DataGroup).Key as CustomMessage;

            return this.Group > targetMessage.Group ? 1 : this.Group == targetMessage.Group ? 0 : -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

public class Person : ViewModelBase
{
    private int personId;
    private string name;
    private Uri picture;

    public int PersonId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.personId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.personId != value)
            {
                this.personId = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("PersonId");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public Uri Picture
    {
        get
        {
            return this.picture;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.picture != value)
            {
                this.picture = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Picture");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is sketch design of my chat window
[image]

As you see according to design incoming messages are shown on the left and outgoing messages are shown on the right. All the messages are in polygon and sorted by timestamp.
I was looking for container like RadConversationView from telerik toolkit, but couldn't find. So I have to develop it by myself. But I'm new to xaml. So I don't know how to create container like that.

Comment: Do you have any specific issue or a specific question that we can help you with?

Comment: I don't know how to create container which could display messages according to incomingMessageTemplate and outgoingMessageTemplate and display them sorting by timestamp. That's my problem

Comment: There are many how-to's available for WPF. For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simply you can achieve this using a ListBox or ListView and set the HorizontalAlignment of Items depending on message type. Hard coded example :

```
  <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Incoming</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Outgoing</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Incoming</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Outgoing</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Outgoing</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Outgoing</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
```

To make it dynamic you can define a ItemContainerStyle and put trigger on MessageType (assuming you message class has this property).

```
 <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageType}" Value="Incoming">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```